# DSR reports VB6 to .net migration

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I have to convert a DSR report from VB6 to rpt report in .net.
How should i achieve this rather to avoid  rewriting of  reports. 
Is their any way to get .net compatible reports?

Answer (score 1):

If you open the DSR from within the VB6 environment, you should have an icon in the top-left of the designer that allows you to save the DSR as a standalone RPT file.